# I would like to display response on the same page about where I sent the request to server

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I have a client-html and server rest. When I send a post to server rest, it returns me a response. I would like to display it on the same page about where I sent the request to server.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: And what is stopping you from displaying results on your page?  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Take the response content and wrappe it in html code. You could do this with javascript. Thats all. One question: What is the content format of your response?

Comment: @David It appears only the response and do not see the page with which I sent the request

Comment: @Patrick Vogt the format are String or json

Comment: @FabioBranch: That doesn't clarify *anything* about the problem.  Include an example of the problem in the question, we can't see your screen from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if your response data is a json object so you could do the following:

For example with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: YOUR_URI,
    ...
    success: function(response) {
         var html = "";
         html += "<p>Hello " response.name + "</p>";
         $(selector).append(html);
    }
});
```

The access to the response object depends on your data structure. I hope this is helpfully for you.